# Computing list elements that refer to earlier elements and two other lists without iteration

Tags: operators, functional

I am attempting to compute the elements of a list, $\{a_i\}$ given lists $\{b_i\}$ and $\{c_i\}$ using the following formula:

$a_i = \frac{1}{c_1}(b_i - \sum_{j = 2}^{i}c_{j}a_{i-j+1})$ for $1\leq i \leq n$.

I was able to implement this formula in an explicit loop, but I would really like to understand how to implement it using some kind of implicit looping construct. I feel it can be done with `Fold[]` or `Map[]` using `Total[]` but I can't quite figure out how to put all the pieces together.

Here is my solution using `For[]`.

```
b = {1, 2, -2, 0, 0, 0};                                                                         
c = {1, -1, -2, 2, 0, 0};                                                                        
n = Length[c];                                                             
a = Table[0,{n}];                                                                                
For[ i = 2, i <= n, i++, 
    a[[i]] = (b[[i]] - Total[c[[2;;i]]*a[[i-1;;1;;-1]]]) / c[[1]] ];
```

It seems to me that it should be possible to do this without having to initialize `a` to an empty list of zeros, use an iterator variable `i`, or explicitly compute the length of `c`. I am very new to Mathematica and a broken down explanation of how to do this in a more functional programming way would be super helpful!

Comment: Sum from j=2 to i=1 is `0`?

Comment: Yes, sum from j = 2 to i=1 is 0.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a memonized function to calculate the values of `a` and `Map` that onto a `Range`.

```
a[i_Integer/;i>0]:=
  a[i]=
  (1/c[[1]]) (b[[i]] - Sum[c[[j]] a[i-j+1],{j,2,i,1}])
a[0]=0;
```

This sets up the function to calculate each `a` and save the value for future use.  Use this to get your values.

```
aList = a[#]&/@Range[Length[c]]
(* {1, 3, 3, 7, 7, 15} *)
```

You can see all the saved values of `a` by evaluating:

```
?a
```

Comment: That does not produce the correct result. Also, I think there should be some simpler way to do it using FoldList or some similar function.

Comment: @bang What result are you expecting?